# mysql query cross multipul tables on condition which maybe null

Tags: mysql

I have three tables, **PERSON**, **TYPE**, **PROJECT** as below
**PERSON** contains 4 columns:

`ID, NAME, TYPE_ID, PROJECT_ID`,`PROJECT_ID` default value is NULL.

**TYPE** contains 2 columns:

`ID, NAME`

**PROJECT** contains 2 columns:

`ID, NAME`

First record in **PERSON** table is

```
| ID | NAME | TYPE_ID | PROJECT_ID |
+----+------+---------+------------+
| 1  | Ryan | 1       | NULL       |
```

now I want to get result as person.id, person.name, type.name, project.name as

1, Ryan, type name, 'empty' with below query.

```
select person.*,type.name,project.name from person left join (type , project) ON (type.id = person.type AND project.id = person.project) where person.`id`= 1
```

I can not get right results of type and project.

Comment: it it really hard to understand your tables and info you provided, could you please reformat it? this will help you [formatting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Thanks for remind.

Comment: did you just copied my editing into your own?) you could have just accepted my edit instead, no?

Comment: did my answer worked for your question?

Comment: yes, works well. Thanks very much. It is my first time to ask questions on this web, forgive my not familiar with its format. Thanks again.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow )

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
SELECT 
      a.ID, 
      a.NAME, 
      b.NAME, 
      c.NAME 
FROM 
      PERSON a LEFT JOIN TYPE b ON (b.ID = a.TYPE_ID)
      LEFT JOIN PROJECT c ON (c.ID = a.PROJECT_ID)
```

I am not sure how it works in Mysql but I think it should be almost the same with Oracle